# Rings in which every irreducible ideal is primary

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose $R$ is a commutative ring with $1$. It is well-known that if $R$ is Noetherian, then every irreducible ideal is primary (Lemma 7.12 in Atiyah & Macdonald). Is the converse true? That is:

> If every irreducible ideal of $R$ is primary, then is it necessarily
>   true that $R$ is Noetherian?

This is just to satisfy my own curiosity. :)

Note the following [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28620/primary-ideals-of-noetherian-rings-which-are-not-irreducible) problem. There, the question is about different converse (which is false).

**Added.** In order to make the post self-contained, I will add the relevant definitions. An ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ is called irreducible if $\mathfrak{a}=\mathfrak{b}\cap\mathfrak{c}$ implies $\mathfrak{a}=\mathfrak{b}$ or $\mathfrak{a}=\mathfrak{c}$. An ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ is called primary if $\mathfrak{a}\neq R$, and for all $x,y\in R$, $xy\in \mathfrak{a}$ implies $x\in\mathfrak{a}$ or $y^{n}\in\mathfrak{a}$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: If $R$ satisfies the ascending chain condition on irreducible ideals then every irreducible ideal is primary.

Comment: @YACP: Thanks! I think you are indicating that there is a counter-example, that is: we just need to find a ring that satisfies ascending chain condition on irreducible ideals, but otherwise is non-Noetherian.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $R$ is a ring with the property that every ideal (excepting $R$ itself) has a (finite) primary decomposition, that is, $R$ is *laskerian*, then every irreducible ideal is primary. Now take a [laskerian ring which is not noetherian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14328/a-non-noetherian-lasker-ring/51041#51041).